# To prove $A \cap B = A$. Given $ A \cup B = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove $A \cap  B = A$.

Given $ A \cup B = B$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: By the axiom of extensionality for a proof of $A\cap B=A$, you have to show that $A\subseteq A\cap B$ and $A\cap B\subseteq A$. The second inclusion is immediate. Why? For the second inclusion start with "Let $x\in A$." Now you have to show that $x\in A\cap B$. This means your prove is done, when you showed that $x\in B$.

Comment: @Cornman It seems like a bit of an overkill to me to say something about axioms here, this is not going to help for such a question. Otherwise I like your comment a lot.

Comment: Both statements are equivalent to $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: @junjios I like to mention the axiom of extensionality to make clear that set equality has a precice meaning. This is often not mentioned in beginner courses. I know barely any book suitable for beginners that discuss this, and I do not understand why. One has to look into specific set-theory books to find this axiom. I do not know how one is expected to prove such a statement, when the method is never really discussed. Also I find it worth to point out that this really is an axiom.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: [This duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462513) makes the (undue) answers below useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is obvious that $A\cap B\subseteq A$. Now, we will take $x\in A$. 
$x\in A \subseteq A\cup B=B\rightarrow x\in B$. Now we have that $x\in  A$ and $x\in B$, so $x\in A\cap B.$
From here, $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A\cap B$ which means $A=A\cap B.
\square$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Thank you! I don't think it will do much help if I'll delete my answer, but next time I will only help someone, and won't tell them the answer!

Answer (score 1):

First let us show that:
$x \in A \cap B \implies x \in A$

If $x$ is in the intersection of $A$ and $B$, it follows that it is in both $A$ and $B$, and therefore in $A$.

Now let us show the other direction:
$x \in A \implies x \in A \cap B$.

If $x$ is in $A$, it is certainly in $A \cup B$, which equals $B$ (by the given assumption.) Therefore, $x \in A \implies x \in B \implies x \in A \cap B$.

Anything in $A$ is in the intersection, and anything in the intersection is in $A$.

$A \cap B=A$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: Look, I understand that this question appears to “lack context.” But clearly that’s because the OP just doesn’t even know where to begin. It’s a simple question that OP got stuck on, do you want them to write a paragraph about how they stared at a blank page of paper for 10 minutes before anyone’s allowed to help them?

Comment: Not that useless "context" but everything described in the 2 links they were provided. The OP is used to edit such naked questions and must not be encouraged to continue. Anyway, this is a duplicate (see link above).

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
A &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) \\
  &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap (A \cup B)^c) \\
  &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap (A^c \cap B^c)) \\
  &= (A \cap B) \cup ((A \cap A^c) \cap B^c)) \\
  &= (A \cap B) \cup (\emptyset \cap B^c)) \\
  &= (A \cap B) \cup \emptyset \\
  &= A \cap B
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Malady Thanks. That was the whole point, haha.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.